# post page with youtube video on facebook which plays directly in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, youtube, facebook-opengraph

Here is my problem, which I haven't been able to fully solve after much searching and experimenting. We have many pages on our site which primarily hold a single YouTube video. I would like that when a viewer Facebook-shares such a page, it will appear in his FB timeline as a page from our site, yet play the YouTube video directly in Facebook.

This is primarily a matter of properly setting the relevant open-graph (og) tags - which I believe I've done correctly. It also used to work for us, but for most videos no longer does (don't know since when).

Anyway, the vast majority of our videos do not play directly in FB. When you click on them, they appear to start playing but then the playing area turns blank. If you right-click the area, a menu appears, with the first (unselectable) item saying "Movie not loaded..."

I have found two video pages on our site which **do** play correctly in FB, and darned if I know what's different about them. My suspicion is that it is some sort of permissions issue with the YouTube channel, as the 2 which do play come from different channels. Beyond that, the OG settings are identical.

Here are two pages which do not embed properly in FB:

http://www.aish.com/v/ho/Rosh_Hashanah_Rock_Anthem.html

http://www.aish.com/v/ho/57973927.html

And here are two which do:

http://www.aish.com/jw/me/Egyptians-Tel-Aviv-U-Valedictorian-Address.html

http://www.aish.com/j/mm/Sicko.html

If anyone can help me solve what the difference is I would be **eternally** grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be a problem with Facebook who needs to cache the video once.

Let me explain : I tried to share this page : http://www.aish.com/v/ho/57973927.html but the *Movie not loaded...* problem appeared. So I tested the link on the [Object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), then I shared it again and it worked fine this time.

So I've tested with the second link : http://www.aish.com/v/ho/Rosh_Hashanah_Rock_Anthem.html I shared it, the problem appeared. I waited few minutes, then I came back to my profile and played the video and it worked fine this time too.

So I think you are the first who share these links, and you have tried to play it too quickly, Facebook didn't have the time to "read" the video.

Try to share your two links now and tell me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Yes, this seems to be fixing the issue. I've always found Facebook to be a little slow on the uptake, not registering updates on our site - sometimes even after using the debugger page to rescrape the page (till I scrape it a second time - or perhaps I'm just not waiting long enough). Either way, thanks again for taking the time to review this!